# How can I make nock respond with an 'undefined' body?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, nock, http-status-code-204

I'm testing a request handler that deals with different situations and one of them expects a response with HTTP code 204 and no response body (`typeof response.body === 'undefined'`).

I tried to set the reply to `null`, `undefined` and not setting it at all. In all these cases, the response body is an empty string (`''`).

Is there a way to delete the response body from Nock?

This is the test I'm trying to run:

```js
it('should return true if body is undefined (usually, 204 status responses - No content)', async () => {
  nock('http://test.com')
    .put('/')
    .reply(204, undefined)
//  .reply(204, null) also fails
//  .reply(204) also fails

 const result = await Request._request('http://test.com', { method: 'PUT' })

 expect(result).to.be.true
})
```

And this is the code I'm trying to test:

```js
static async _request (url, options) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      request(url, options)
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.statusCode < 300) {
            if (typeof response.body === 'undefined') {
              resolve(true)
            } else if (isJSON(response.body)) {
              resolve(JSON.parse(response.body.replace(/\s/g, ' ')))
            } else {
              .
              .
              .
```

Comment: @Derek No it's not, the code is checking if `typeof response.body == 'undefined'` (note the `typeof`).

Comment: @Eduardo Russo - why do you expect `undefined` there in the first place? There is nothing in HTTP that could distinguish an empty body from an "undefined" one. Since we are talking about a piece of data with size zero, it's hard to prove or disprove its existence at the end of the response data.

Comment: An empty string is falsy, so `!response.body` would be a more robust check anyway. Or just test for the 204 ("No Content") status code. Nock doesn't do anything special with an undefined body parameter to reply: https://github.com/nock/nock/blob/ad7e481d35035d41061dff970ab4f0eefe7a1d02/lib/interceptor.js#L112-L189

Comment: I'll try to answer everyone in the same response, as I believe they are all about "why am I doing what I'm doing".

The API I'm using (Jira) when I update an issue with PUT responds with a 204 without a body, so, checking (on my code) if body is not defined works. So, I added this case (`typeof response.body === 'undefined'`) to be able to deal with this specific case and it works, so I was trying to test this specific case.

I will replace my code as suggested by @jonrsharpe, as it will work both for the real Jira response and also for the test to cover it.

Comment: I opened a "bug" on Nock, because I still think there's a case for "empty" body, but I'll be able to change my code and carry on. Thanks for the answer, guys

Comment: @EduardoRusso I responded to your github issue on Nock, but for anyone else looking for help on this. Nock will, correctly, not provide response data if the `reply` method is not given a second argument. However, how your given client interprets the lack of data varies by implementation. As stated previously, when using the `request` lib, `!response.body` is the preferred way to check.

Comment: I will add: looking at your `_request` function, there is an assumption that any status code under 300 without a body was successful. If this function is going to be used in a system that needs to be robust, that assumption is dangerous. For a non-204 there is a chance the server sent a body, but the client didn't receive it.